# Cannot paste text content in textarea or textbox

Tags: textarea, clipboard

For some reason I cannot paste this block of text in any textarea in the browser. It's not even a large content but pasting does not work.

You can try copy/paste the text here:

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/bn9hx3vt/]
```

Copy all text and paste it, it will not paste. but if you copy partially and paste. It works.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I can't view the linked resource. I get the message "_Deleted. The transfer you requested has been deleted._" Please provide a [mre]. Would it be possible for you to provide a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/11107541)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. can you try here? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TB0PJE2S0QYBK0GN6K45aGeXdrag7JxV/view

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments. Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them. And no, that does not work. I can't view it without signing in to Google. If I need to sign in to anything other than Stack Exchange to view any details needed to understand a problem, that's wrong.

Comment: Actually that is the problem. because I can't paste the content. so if someone will like to test, they should really copy/paste the content.

Comment: You said you can paste partially. Then how about your paste partially until it's all pasted into your question post? If you can't do that, then you should at least do everything you possibly can to describe in words what might make that block of text special compared to any other block of text.

Comment: Thanks, Sorry about that. yes, partially pasting did create a snippet. here it is. https://jsfiddle.net/bn9hx3vt/

Comment: So, just try to copy all text and paste it in any textbox or textarea in the browser. not in text editor.

Comment: Is this a [mre]? Is this the smallest possible text that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Yes. That is the text that I can't paste. which is the issue. you see its not really a large text. but for some reason the paste fails. Hope you can give me the explanation why it fails cuz I been tasks to investigate that issue. Thanks